# How to add a CSS class to an XML item?

Tags: css, xml

Is it possible to add a CSS class to an item in a XML file? The reason for adding a class is because i want to be able to change the color of the item from the XML file by switching between 3 classes. So I would just style the 3 classes and then switch between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="main.css" media="screen" type="text/css"?>
   <root>
      <item row="1" span="4" name="Develop">
         <item name="Idea" row="2" classname="test">
             <item shape="arrow" span="8" name="Project Management"></item>
             <item name="Concept, Technology &amp; Layout"></item>
             <item name="Consent" span="6" shape="arrow"></item>
             <item shape="arrow" span="8" name="Engineering"></item>
             <item shape="arrow" name="Commercial"></item>
             <item name="Operation Preparation"></item>
          </item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below code and check.

```
item {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Does not work since I want to add a class like this: <item name="Idea" row="2" classname="test">.

Comment: Replace your classname="test" with class="test" and try.

Answer (score 1):

Where the xml rendered in? If you render it on browser then regular styling will work. Example:

```css
plist {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<plist>
  <item class="yellow">One</item>
  <item>Two</item>
</plist>
```